# An upper bound for the length of the continued fraction expansion of $\sqrt d$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, continued-fractions

Let $d\ge 2$ and let 
$$
\sqrt d =[a_0; \overline{a_1,\dots, a_\ell, 2a_0}]
$$
be its continued fraction expansion. Clearly, if $d=n^2+1$, then $\ell=0$, which gives the lower bound for $\ell$.

**Question.** What is the best known upper bound for $\ell=\ell(d)$ as a function of $d$?

For instance, $\ell(d)=O(d)$ is fairly trivial, following from the well-known algorithm (see [Rockett-Szusz], for instance). However, I suspect something like $O(\sqrt d)$ (or $O(\sqrt d\log d$) must be known.

Comment: What can you say about numbers $d$ where $l$ is 1 or 2?  Is it conceivable that the upper bound is constant? Gerhard "If You Dream, Dream Big" Paseman, 2015.04.16

Comment: No, this is not possible. For instance, $\ell(2^{2k+1}\asymp 5^k$, according to E. Golubeva (1990). Apparently, this was already known in the 19th century.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is known that $\ell(d)=O(\sqrt{d}\log d)$ and $\ell(d)=\Omega(\sqrt{d}/\log\log d)$.

See [Cohn's paper](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102811631) (free access) for more details.

For numerical results and some further historical comments see [Williams's paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2007664).

Comment: That $\Omega$ is not consistent with the cases of $\ell=0$ in the question.  I think it actually says $\ell(d)$ is not $o(\sqrt{d}/\log\log d)$.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar: In analytic number theory, $f(x)=\Omega(g(x))$ means that $f(x)=o(g(x))$ is false, and I followed that convention. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#The_Hardy.E2.80.93Littlewood_definition

Comment: @GHfromMO Is there a relation between length of periods and factoring?

Comment: @VS.: I don't know.